# why is PID 0 reading/writing large amounts of data

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, pid

Just booted my PC up and it was running slower than usual. I went into the resource monitor and its saying that System PID 0 is reading and writing 100,000,000B/sec and its accessing all drives for 50% usage. the 
[picture of resource monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQk25.png)
Any ideas what causing it and how i can fix it? thank you

Just a note to add i was looking at my hard drives and its saying that my Raid 1 drives are resyncing. could that cause this issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it apears that the reasons it was reading and writing large amounts of data was due to my Raid 1 drives be desyncranised. good news is i fixed it the bad news i broke my raid so i now have 2 seperate drives :/

little update:
I removed one of my drives from the mirror raid, formated it and then added it back to the mirror drive. Just had to wait for it to write all the data from the one of the drives to the other that I formated :)

If anyone want I can make a video or a google doc to show how to fix it :)